# Laravel Error. Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install a script.

I have Laravel version: 8.41.0
PHP version: 8.1.2

While trying to do 'composer update' getting this error.

--ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1352

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1352
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1363

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1363
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1375

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1375
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1388

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1388
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 141

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 141
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 152

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 152
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 164

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 164
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 175

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 175
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php:1443
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', '/Applications/X...', 1443)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('/Applications/X...')
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Applications/X...')
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130): collect(Array)
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php on line 13
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Collection" not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ReflectsClosures.php(24): collect(Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ReflectsClosures.php(43): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->closureParameterTypes(Object(Closure))
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/ReportableHandler.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->firstClosureParameterType(Object(Closure))
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(232): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->handles(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(88): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php on line 15
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the package you are trying to install that gives this error?

Comment: Package spatie/data-transfer-object is abandoned,  Use spatie/laravel-data.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned,  Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler.
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Razorpay\Tests\registerNachTest located in ./vendor/razorpay/razorpay/tests/registerNachtest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Razorpay\Tests\fundTest located in ./vendor/razorpay/razorpay/tests/FundTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.